# How to show blank when value is repeated

Tags: sql, mariadb

```
SELECT * FROM Cities ORDER BY Country;
```

This is the result.

```
COUNTRY         CITY           PLACE
Italy           Milan          Zone_A
Italy           Rome           Zone_A  
Italy           Rome           Zone_B
USA             New York       Zone_Q
USA             Atlanta        Zone_A
```

I would like to create a Stored Procedure that shows "blank" when the item is repeated. The final result should be the following. (Note that this rule is applied only in the first 2 columns, not in the third).

```
COUNTRY         CITY           PLACE
Italy           Milan          Zone_A
                Rome           Zone_A  
                               Zone_B
USA             New York       Zone_Q
                Atlanta        Zone_A
```

Comment: Fix it in the presentation layer instead.

Comment: Why do you want a result such as this?

Comment: @SalmanA ahahah my employer wants that.. I completely disagree with that :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your version of maria DB supports window functions, you can use `lag()`:

```
select
    case when lag(country) over(order by country, city, place) = country
        then null
        else country
    end country,
    case when lag(city) over(order by country, city, place) = city
        then null
        else city
    end city,
    place
from cities
order by
    country,
    city,
    place
```